# flutter jump to another widget

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, singlechildscrollview

I want to click on the button and jump to the next widget in my `SingleChildScrollView` but I have to pass height in the controller and I have a text widget and I don't know what is the height of text because there came from the server.
so can anyone help me please how can I jump to the second container in my `SingleChildScrollView`?

here is my button I want to press :

```
 IconButton(
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              splashColor: Colors.transparent,
              hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              constraints: BoxConstraints(),
              onPressed: () {
                scrollController.animateTo(
                    500.0, // here
                    curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1800 ));
              },
              icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                MyIcons.message3,
              ),
            ),
```

it's my controller :

```
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
```

here is my code :

```
 SingleChildScrollView(
 controller: scrollController,
 child: Column(
 children: [
   text(),
  Container()
 ]));
```

I just want to jump to text and receive to the container when I click on the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using keys.

Declare a unique key for your Container() widget.

```
final containerKey = GlobalKey();
```

Assign this key to your container:

```
Container(
   key: containerKey,
   ...
),
```

On the click of your button do the following:

```
scrollController.position.ensureVisible(
  containerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject(),
  alignment: 0.5, // How far into view (between 0 and 1).
  duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
);
```

Make sure your scrollController is assigned to your SingleChildScrollView.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    controller: scrollController,
    child: ...
)
```

Comment: i got `error: The argument type 'RenderObject?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'RenderObject'. `

Comment: i have error from this part `containerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject()`

Comment: Try adding a null check operator

```containerKey.currentContext.findRenderObject()!```

Comment: ok. I have no errors but not work.

Comment: Try changing alignment and giving it a fresh restart.

Comment: i useed this : `containerKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()!` and i got ` Null check operator used on a null value` and i cant use findRenderObject with another shape i have to use `!` . . i dont think so is related to alignment

Comment: You assigned `containerKey` to your widget you want to jump on? Also make sure the button and container both shares same context.

Comment: on now when i print `containerKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()!` i got  `RenderConstrainedBox#8dbd5 relayoutBoundary=up42` and still not work

Comment: The code I suggested is working with me, I am sure there is something wrong with your Container widget, try giving it a height or something.

Answer (score 0):

mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, Add this line in column

```
SingleChildScrollView(
controller: scrollController,
child: Column(
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
children: [
text(),
Container()
]));
```